# Implementing a simple proxy server using node.js

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, https, proxy-server

I'm trying to create a simple node.js proxy server for experimental purposes and I came up with this simple script:

```
var url = require("url");
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var path = url.parse(request.url).path;

    if (!path.indexOf("/resource/")) {
        var protocol;
        path = path.slice(10);
        var location = url.parse(path);

        switch (location.protocol) {
        case "http:":
            protocol = http;
            break;
        case "https:":
            protocol = https;
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(400);
            response.end();
            return;
        }

        var options = {
            host: location.host,
            hostname: location.hostname,
            port: +location.port,
            method: request.method,
            path: location.path,
            headers: request.headers,
            auth: location.auth
        };

        var clientRequest = protocol.request(options, function (clientResponse) {
            response.writeHead(clientResponse.statusCode, clientResponse.headers);
            clientResponse.on("data", response.write);
            clientResponse.on("end", function () {
                response.addTrailers(clientResponse.trailers);
                response.end();
            });
        });

        request.on("data", clientRequest.write);
        request.on("end", clientRequest.end);
    } else {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end();
    }
}).listen(8484);
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong but it gives me the following error when I try to load any page:

```
http.js:645
    this._implicitHeader();
         ^
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method '_implicitHeader'
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (http.js:645:10)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:137:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1410:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:374:27)
```

I wonder what could the problem be. Debugging in node.js is so much more difficult than in Rhino. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ran the code on my own computer. Thus I opened it in my web browser by going to `http://localhost:8484/resource/http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js`. It should have fetched the `jquery.js` file and forwarded it but instead it gave me the aforementioned error.

Comment: My initial guess would be that it's because of the way you are passing  the functions to 'data' and 'end'. Can you try passing anonymous functions that call `clientRequest.write()` and `clientRequest.end()`? The way you have it now, you are passing the function, but when it gets called it won't have the proper context (`this`).

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the URL contents? The URL after 'resource'

Comment: @loganfsmyth - I'll bind the functions to the correct contexts and try again. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @AseemGautam - Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - Alright, so I replaced `clientRequest.write` with `clientRequest.write.bind(clientRequest)`, `clientRequest.end` with `clientRequest.end.bind(clientRequest)` and `response.write` with `response.write.bind(response)`. It doesn't give me any errors now, but it doesn't load the correct page either. For example when I go to `http://localhost:8484/resource/http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js` it gives me a 404 error. Naturally it must have come from some other domain because my proxy doesn't have the logic to generate a 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your primary problem is that your `.write` and `.end` calls are not bound properly to a context, so they will just flip out and throw errors all over.

With that fixed, requests give a 404 because the `headers` property will pull in the `host` header of the original request, `localhost:8484`. Following your example, that will get send to jquery.com's server, and it will 404. You need to remove the `host` header before proxying.

Add this before calling `protocol.request`.

```
delete options.headers.host;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works like a charm. I thought it would be a good idea to set `options.headers.host` to point to `location.host` instead of deleting it. =)